# how to merge array with same value

Tags: php, arrays

when i echo my array it's looks like this

```
 [0] => Array
    (
        [carriertype] => 
        [radiotype] => RRUS 12 B2
        [serialnumber] => CF82943634
        [market] => Detroit Westland - DET 5
        [bts] => 225011
        [Host] => 225011_21_MILE_and_ROMEO_PLANK
        [resourceId] => 0
        [type] => XMU
        [port] => 16
        [EP_AuxPlugInUnit_AuxPlugInUnitId] => RRU-7
        [userlabletext] => 225011_1_4
        [flag] => Yes
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [carriertype] => 
        [radiotype] => RRUS 12 B2
        [serialnumber] => CF82961338
        [market] => Detroit Westland - DET 5
        [bts] => 225011
        [Host] => 225011_21_MILE_and_ROMEO_PLANK
        [resourceId] => 0
        [type] => XMU
        [port] => 15
        [EP_AuxPlugInUnit_AuxPlugInUnitId] => RRU-8
        [userlabletext] => 225011_2_4
        [flag] => Yes
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [carriertype] => 
        [radiotype] => RRUS 12 B2
        [serialnumber] => CF82943628
        [market] => Detroit Westland - DET 5
        [bts] => 225011
        [Host] => 225011_21_MILE_and_ROMEO_PLANK
        [resourceId] => 0
        [type] => XMU
        [port] => 14
        [EP_AuxPlugInUnit_AuxPlugInUnitId] => RRU-9
        [userlabletext] => 225011_3_4
        [flag] => Yes
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [radiotype] => 
        [carriertype] => 
        [serialnumber] => 
        [market] => Detroit Westland - DET 5
        [bts] => 225011
        [Host] => 225011_21_MILE_and_ROMEO_PLANK
        [resourceId] => 0
        [type] => XMU
        [port] => 1
        [EP_AuxPlugInUnit_AuxPlugInUnitId] => 
        [userlabletext] => ___B
        [flag] => Yes
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [radiotype] => 
        [carriertype] => 
        [serialnumber] => 
        [market] => Detroit Westland - DET 5
        [bts] => 225011
        [Host] => 225011_21_MILE_and_ROMEO_PLANK
        [resourceId] => 0
        [type] => XMU
        [port] => 1
        [EP_AuxPlugInUnit_AuxPlugInUnitId] => 
        [userlabletext] => ___E
        [flag] => Yes
    )

[5] => Array
    (
        [carriertype] => AWS
        [radiotype] => RRUS 12 B4
        [serialnumber] => CF81666912
        [market] => Detroit Westland - DET 5
        [bts] => 225011
        [Host] => 225011_21_MILE_and_ROMEO_PLANK
        [resourceId] => 0
        [type] => XMU
        [port] => 16
        [EP_AuxPlugInUnit_AuxPlugInUnitId] => RRU-5
        [userlabletext] => 225011_2_2
        [flag] => Yes
    )

[6] => Array
    (
        [carriertype] => AWS
        [radiotype] => RRUS 12 B4
        [serialnumber] => CF81666918
        [market] => Detroit Westland - DET 5
        [bts] => 225011
        [Host] => 225011_21_MILE_and_ROMEO_PLANK
        [resourceId] => 0
        [type] => XMU
        [port] => 14
        [EP_AuxPlugInUnit_AuxPlugInUnitId] => RRU-6
        [userlabletext] => 225011_3_2
        [flag] => Yes
    )
```

but i want array merge with same **port** value. in above array i have two 16,14 and 1 port nos. so they should merge with same value and if some value is differ then it should be save with comma between value. resulting array should like

```
 [0] => Array
    (
        [carriertype] => AWS
        [radiotype] => RRUS 12 B2,RRUS 12 B4
        [serialnumber] => CF82943634,CF81666912
        [market] => Detroit Westland - DET 5
        [bts] => 225011
        [Host] => 225011_21_MILE_and_ROMEO_PLANK
        [resourceId] => 0
        [type] => XMU
        [port] => 16
        [EP_AuxPlugInUnit_AuxPlugInUnitId] => RRU-7,RRU-5
        [userlabletext] => 225011_1_4,225011_2_2
        [flag] => Yes
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [carriertype] => 
        [radiotype] => RRUS 12 B2
        [serialnumber] => CF82961338
        [market] => Detroit Westland - DET 5
        [bts] => 225011
        [Host] => 225011_21_MILE_and_ROMEO_PLANK
        [resourceId] => 0
        [type] => XMU
        [port] => 15
        [EP_AuxPlugInUnit_AuxPlugInUnitId] => RRU-8
        [userlabletext] => 225011_2_4
        [flag] => Yes
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [carriertype] => AWS
        [radiotype] => RRUS 12 B2,RRUS 12 B4
        [serialnumber] => CF82943628,CF81666918
        [market] => Detroit Westland - DET 5
        [bts] => 225011
        [Host] => 225011_21_MILE_and_ROMEO_PLANK
        [resourceId] => 0
        [type] => XMU
        [port] => 14
        [EP_AuxPlugInUnit_AuxPlugInUnitId] => RRU-9,RRU-6
        [userlabletext] => 225011_3_4,225011_3_2
        [flag] => Yes
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [radiotype] => 
        [carriertype] => 
        [serialnumber] => 
        [market] => Detroit Westland - DET 5
        [bts] => 225011
        [Host] => 225011_21_MILE_and_ROMEO_PLANK
        [resourceId] => 0
        [type] => XMU
        [port] => 1
        [EP_AuxPlugInUnit_AuxPlugInUnitId] => 
        [userlabletext] => ___B,___E
        [flag] => Yes
    )
```

it should be done programmatic. please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
<?php

/**
 * @param array  $array
 * @param string $column
 *
 * @return array
 */
function mergeOnEquals(array $array, $column)
{
    $result = [];

    foreach ($array as $subArray) {
        $index = $subArray[$column];
        if (isset($result[$index])) {
            foreach($subArray as $key => $value) {
                if (!isset($result[$index][$key]) || $result[$index][$key] == '') {
                    $result[$index][$key] = $value;
                } elseif ($result[$index][$key] != $value) {
                    $result[$index][$key] .= ",$value";
                }
            }
        } else {
            $result[$index] = $subArray;
        }
    }

    return array_values($result);
}

$array = [
    [
        'carriertype'                      => null,
        'radiotype'                        => 'RRUS 12 B2',
        'serialnumber'                     => 'CF82943634',
        'market'                           => 'Detroit Westland - DET 5',
        'bts'                              => 225011,
        'Host'                             => '225011_21_MILE_and_ROMEO_PLANK',
        'resourceId'                       => 0,
        'type'                             => 'XMU',
        'port'                             => 16,
        'EP_AuxPlugInUnit_AuxPlugInUnitId' => 'RRU-7',
        'userlabletext'                    => '225011_1_4',
        'flag'                             => 'Yes',
    ],
    [
        'carriertype'                      => null,
        'radiotype'                        => 'RRUS 12 B2',
        'serialnumber'                     => 'CF82961338',
        'market'                           => 'Detroit Westland - DET 5',
        'bts'                              => 225011,
        'Host'                             => '225011_21_MILE_and_ROMEO_PLANK',
        'resourceId'                       => 0,
        'type'                             => 'XMU',
        'port'                             => 15,
        'EP_AuxPlugInUnit_AuxPlugInUnitId' => 'RRU-8',
        'userlabletext'                    => '225011_2_4',
        'flag'                             => 'Yes',
    ],
    [
        'carriertype'                      => null,
        'radiotype'                        => 'RRUS 12 B2',
        'serialnumber'                     => 'CF82943628',
        'market'                           => 'Detroit Westland - DET 5',
        'bts'                              => '225011',
        'Host'                             => '225011_21_MILE_and_ROMEO_PLANK',
        'resourceId'                       => 0,
        'type'                             => 'XMU',
        'port'                             => 14,
        'EP_AuxPlugInUnit_AuxPlugInUnitId' => 'RRU-9',
        'userlabletext'                    => '225011_3_4',
        'flag'                             => 'Yes',
    ],
    [
        'radiotype'                        => null,
        'carriertype'                      => null,
        'serialnumber'                     => null,
        'market'                           => 'Detroit Westland - DET 5',
        'bts'                              => 225011,
        'Host'                             => '225011_21_MILE_and_ROMEO_PLANK',
        'resourceId'                       => 0,
        'type'                             => 'XMU',
        'port'                             => 1,
        'EP_AuxPlugInUnit_AuxPlugInUnitId' => null,
        'userlabletext'                    => '___B',
        'flag'                             => 'Yes',
    ],
    [
        'radiotype'                        => null,
        'carriertype'                      => null,
        'serialnumber'                     => null,
        'market'                           => 'Detroit Westland - DET 5',
        'bts'                              => 225011,
        'Host'                             => '225011_21_MILE_and_ROMEO_PLANK',
        'resourceId'                       => 0,
        'type'                             => 'XMU',
        'port'                             => 1,
        'EP_AuxPlugInUnit_AuxPlugInUnitId' => null,
        'userlabletext'                    => '___E',
        'flag'                             => 'Yes',
    ],
    [
        'carriertype'                      => 'AWS',
        'radiotype'                        => 'RRUS 12 B4',
        'serialnumber'                     => 'CF81666912',
        'market'                           => 'Detroit Westland - DET 5',
        'bts'                              => 225011,
        'Host'                             => '225011_21_MILE_and_ROMEO_PLANK',
        'resourceId'                       => 0,
        'type'                             => 'XMU',
        'port'                             => 16,
        'EP_AuxPlugInUnit_AuxPlugInUnitId' => 'RRU-5',
        'userlabletext'                    => '225011_2_2',
        'flag'                             => 'Yes',
    ],
    [
        'carriertype'                      => 'AWS',
        'radiotype'                        => 'RRUS 12 B4',
        'serialnumber'                     => 'CF81666918',
        'market'                           => 'Detroit Westland - DET 5',
        'bts'                              => 225011,
        'Host'                             => '225011_21_MILE_and_ROMEO_PLANK',
        'resourceId'                       => 0,
        'type'                             => 'XMU',
        'port'                             => 14,
        'EP_AuxPlugInUnit_AuxPlugInUnitId' => 'RRU-6',
        'userlabletext'                    => '225011_3_2',
        'flag'                             => 'Yes',
    ],
];

print_r(mergeOnEquals($array, 'port'));
```

[Live demo](https://3v4l.org/gCXIu).

Comment: i made small change with  if($result[$index][$key]!=""){$result[$index][$key] .= ",$value";}else{$result[$index][$key] .= "$value";}...and it work...thanks...it's very helpful.

Comment: @DivyeshJesadiya I've fixed the issue in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this approach (Please add required validation):

```
$myArray = your main array;

foreach($myArray as $k=>$data)
{
    $port[$data["port"]][]= $k ;

}
$key = array("carriertype",   "radiotype" ,    "serialnumber",
    "market",   "bts" ,    "Host" ,   "resourceId",   "type" ,   "port" , "EP_AuxPlugInUnit_AuxPlugInUnitId", "userlabletext" , "flag");


$ret = array();
foreach($port as $arrdata)
{
    $retArr = array();
    foreach($arrdata as $data)
    {

        foreach($key as $k)
        {
           if($k !='flag' || $k !='port')
           {
               $retArr[$k]= !empty($retArr[$k]) ? $retArr[$k].",".$a[$data][$k] : $a[$data][$k];
           }
           else
           {
              $retArr[$k]= $a[$data][$k];
           }

       }

   }
   $ret[] = $retArr;

}
```